# I have a asp.net mvc application divided into multiple layers.

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, azure

now how i can deploy the application into azure with different layers. I have a data access layer business logic layer and mvc application layer?

Comment: It's best to use the title to ask a question or at least to make a problem statement.  Using it to provide info about the general context of the issue without stating the issue or question makes it hard for others find the answer to solve their similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to deploy directly into azure through Visual Studio. Right click on your project and Click on publish. You can find a more detailed tutorial on [MSDN website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2015/07/20/using-visual-studio-2015-and-deploying-your-first-web-app-to-your-free-azure-subscription/)

Comment: Will it publish all the layers for suppose other than mvc layer if i right click on other layer application i don't see the publish option i have entity framework in the application and i don't know if my applicationpublished entity framework or not?

Comment: @patrick If you are using Entity Framework you should have its dll referenced in the project anyways so it will be published. And also yes it compiles your project (and therefore all the dependencies such as the Business Logic Layer and Data Access Layer) and copies over the binaries.